# Why is javascript looping through elements but executing jQuery function on all of them simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a text "HELLO" and I want to loop through every letter and animate it so it fades in and out.Here's my code.

EDIT: I put the answer in the snippet to see it in action.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $letters = $('p[id^="letter-"');
  $letters.each(function(index) {
    $(this).css({
      'animation': 'pulse 500ms ' + index * 500 + 'ms' + ' linear'
    })
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 45px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 100px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  75% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='letter-0'>H</p>
<p id='letter-1'>E</p>
<p id='letter-2'>L</p>
<p id='letter-3'>L</p>
<p id='letter-4'>O</p>
```

And here's a link to a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRMRJP).
Instead of doing the animation one letter at a time, it's animating the whole thing at once.How can this be fixed? Shouldn't a loop finish executing all the commands and *then* move on to the next step? Maybe there's a better approach to this that I don't know of?

Comment: The loop isn't doing animation, it's just changing CSS. The browser performs the animation when the Javascript finishes.

Comment: To expand on @Barmar's, the loop is executing within milliseconds, so the classes are added so closely the animations appear to start at the same time. It's not waiting for the first animation to finish before starting the next.

Comment: @Barmar So the loop assigns the css to all the elements and then the browser executes it all at once ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to start animations at different times, you could use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to delay changing each CSS.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Oh I get it. So is there any way of doing this other than setting the css by hand ?

Comment: You could also use jQuery `.animate()`, and use the callback function for element N to start the animation for element N+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you should definitely correct is the naming of your `id`s. A single number is [not a valid `id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

A better option might be to name them something like `letter-0`, `letter-1`, etc.

Next, you can use the `animation-delay` property to offset the start of each animation. We'll use the shorthand `animation` property. To do this, we'll find each element with an `id` starting with `letter-`, then loop through them. For each consecutive letter we'll add the animation, and include an animation delay of `500ms` * its position index in the string. For example, the first letter (index `0`) will have an animation delay of `0ms`. The second letter (index `1`) will have an animation delay of `500ms`, and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $letters = $('p[id^="letter-"');
  $letters.each(function(index) {
    $(this).css({
      'animation': 'pulse 500ms ' + index * 500 + 'ms' + ' linear'
    })
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 45px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 100px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  75% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='letter-0'>H</p>
<p id='letter-1'>E</p>
<p id='letter-2'>L</p>
<p id='letter-3'>L</p>
<p id='letter-4'>O</p>
```

Comment: This is actually what I had in mind.I just thought that the normal loop will work like python and wait until one animation stops to start the next one.

Comment: I improved the solution, including a note about the `id`s you're using.

Comment: This is great.The only thing I don't get is where the value of the "index" argument is coming from.Does jQuery automatically assign "$letters" to it because it's the variable that the function is being call on ?

Comment: The [jQuery `.each` method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is passed the current loop iteration each time its called. In this case, `each()` is being called on the `$letters` array, and I'm passing a name (`index`) to the callback function to use as the variable name for the iteration index. On the first iteration of the `each()` loop, `index` is `0`, on the 2nd loop `index` is `1`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `animation-delay` in combination with your loop variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#' + i).css({
      'animation': 'pulse 0.5s linear',
      'animation-delay': i + 's'
    })
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 45px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 100px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  75% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='0'>H</p>
<p id='1'>E</p>
<p id='2'>L</p>
<p id='3'>L</p>
<p id='4'>O</p>
```

Comment: Could you copy the snippet and edit your change into it, so we can see it in action?